# Using Multiple Surfaces Views For Optimization?

Tags: android, optimization, android-view, surfaceview

**The Situation**

I started developing for Android, and found that Android's way of handling layouts, animations etc. is not adequate for smooth touch feedback and real-time animations, especially before Android 4.0. So instead, I decided to use the game app approach: use a `SurfaceView` and define my own drawing code.

**The Problem**

After a few tests, I discovered that this method required too much CPU for a non-game app, which I believe is due to redrawing static elements 60 times per second.

**The First Solution & Flaws**

To solve this issue, I modified my code so that the app would redraw the screen (call `postInvalidate`) only if there were any changes to what should be drawn. This solution solved part of the issue, but the app still had to redraw static elements even if a small button moved a single pixel.

**The Question: Possible Better Solution?**

For a better solution, I considered how Android dealt with the problem; it had separate `View`'s for every screen element. So I though, maybe I could have one `SurfaceView` for large, static, content elements and another for small, moving UI elements and achieve a similar effect. My question is, would this actually improve performance the way I described it above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you're using `postInvalidate()`, you should be using a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), not a SurfaceView.  The whole point of using a SurfaceView is to have a separate layer that is independent of the View UI.  If you're overriding `onDraw()`, you're drawing on the View part, not the Surface part, and just wasting the Surface.
2. All Views occupy a single layer, no matter how many you have.  Each SurfaceView has a separate layer, so having a lot of them will become problematic.  In practice you can have no more than three, because of Z-ordering limitations.  (See the "multi-surface test" activity in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) for an example of three partially transparent SurfaceViews blended with the View UI.)
3. If you can't render fast enough to maintain 60 fps, you need to consider changing the way you render.  Custom Views and OpenGL ES take advantage of hardware acceleration.  Canvas rendering onto a SurfaceView Surface does not.  On the plus side, you can down-size a SurfaceView's Surface and let the hardware scale it back up; this lets you limit the number of pixels you have to draw each frame, regardless of the display's resolution.  ([Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html), [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpRaD-ij2xc).)  If you have a lot of static elements, the best approach may be to render to an off-screen Bitmap, and then just blit the Bitmap every frame.

One approach that will be very fast is to render all of the static elements onto the View part of the SurfaceView, taking care to keep the background transparent, and then render the animated parts on the Surface with GLES.  You could use a second SurfaceView, but that adds an additional composition layer, which will degrade system performance if you exceed the number of overlay planes supported by the hardware.

For a deeper understanding of the way Android graphics work, take a look at the [graphics architecture doc](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).

Comment: Actually, by SurfaceView, I meant a custom view class that extends SurfaceView, that overrides `onDraw()`. I call `postInvalidate()` from a separate thread after calling `lockCanvas()`. Running my app on a test device, `canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()` actually returns `true`. Would this count as drawing on a Surface part? I would have looked through all of the links you provided first, but it looked like something that would take quite some time to take in so... I apologize.

Comment: The SurfaceView has two parts, the Surface and the View. The View part works like other View elements, with `onDraw()` called as part of the invalidate / redraw cycle, and is hardware-accelerated. The Surface part is a completely independent layer, positioned behind the View UI; it can be rendered in software with Canvas, hardware with OpenGL ES, receive frames from the Camera or video decoder, etc. If you don't draw on the View part, the View just acts as a transparent window, letting you see the Surface behind. (It needs to be there for the layout code to have something to measure against.)